# How to call a command in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I want to start the eww browser in Emacs 24.4. I found in documentation that to do this: "To start the web browser, call eww."[1]

However, I cannot figure out how to call this command. How do I call the eww command in Emacs?

[1] http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_eww_web_browser.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That link's use of the word "call" is used because there is more than one way to invoke it. For a quick demo, just type:

```
Meta-x  (Esc and lowercase x)
eww    (type this in the lower command prompt in emacs)
```

This will prompt for "Enter URL or keywords:", and you might just type  www.google.com

The above is a typical emacs cmd invocation. You could also write an emacs macro that took the currently highlighted text, etc.

Note some web pages seem to require non-default libraries.

Comment: Thanks! I just went through the first Emacs tutorial and am starting to get comfortable, but I could not find how to do this anywhere. It was exactly what I needed.